# Ordernar palavras vindas do BD Mysql conforme suas respectivas colunas

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

> tb_dispensa_medica
>
> IdDispensa | IdEmpresa | IdUsuario | PS | SS | TS | QS

As colunas PS, SS, TS e QS são do tipo CHAR(1) que armazenam strings S ou N. Estou precisando ordenar por nome conforme as respectivas colunas, por ex.: Primeira semana (corresponde aos resultados da coluna PS), Segunda semana (corresponde aos resultados da coluna SS), Terceira semana (corresponde aos resultados da coluna TS) e Quarta semana (corresponde aos resultados da coluna QS). Para isso estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
....
    $sqlVisualiza = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_dispensa_medica WHERE IdUsuario = '".$peVisualizar->IdUsuario."'");
    while($peVisualiza = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlVisualiza)){
      if($peVisualiza->PS == 'S'){ $visualizar .= '<p>Primeira semana</p>'; }
      if($peVisualiza->SS == 'S'){ $visualizar .= '<p>Segunda semana</p>'; }
      if($peVisualiza->TS == 'S'){ $visualizar .= '<p>Terceira semana</p>'; }
      if($peVisualiza->QS == 'S'){ $visualizar .= '<p>Quarta semana</p>'; }            
    }
    ....
    return $visualizar;
```

Só que ele está me retornando dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei o sort conforme abaixo, mas não obtive êxito:

```
 if($peVisualiza->PS == 'S'){ $a = '<p>Primeira semana</p>'; }
 if($peVisualiza->SS == 'S'){ $b = '<p>Segunda semana</p>'; }
 if($peVisualiza->TS == 'S'){ $c = '<p>Terceira semana</p>'; }
 if($peVisualiza->QS == 'S'){ $d = '<p>Quarta semana</p>'; }            
 $array = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
 sort($array);
 foreach($array as $val){
         $visualizar .= $val;
 }
```

Como eu poderia ordenar corretamente?

Comment: Olá Bacco. Obrigado por indicar alguns links, mas nenhum corresponde ao meu problema, pois estou precisando ordenar os resultados conforme as colunas, ou seja, os resultados do PS venha primeiro, do SS em segundo, TS em terceiro e do QS venha por último. Tentei usar o sort(), mas não obtive êxito. Inclui minha nova tentativa no post.

Comment: E é exatamente o que tem nos posts linkados, bastaria um `ORDER BY ps="N",ss="N",ts="N",qs="N"` não (talvez decrescente)?

Comment: E aproveitei editei o título e uma parte do post para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: Ou se preferir um `ORDER BY FIELD( 'S', ps, ss, ts, qs )`

Comment: Se bem que no caso parece é que vc tem um problema sério na modelagem, mas ai ja foge da pergunta.

Comment: Tem razão Baco. Acho que o problema está na modelagem. Irei reformular a tabela. Peço desculpas pelo tempo perdido e obrigado.

Comment: Teste o order by field, acredito que resolva se for manter a modelagem atual.